# Getting column from two dimensional array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm currently trying to make a game with 2 players and in order to check the field I need to check the columns of the array instead of the rows

This is the code I currently have:

```
    /*    Array containing the playing field 8 x 8 

       C0 C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7
    R0[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]
    R1[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]
    R2[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0] 
    R3[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0] 
    R4[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]
    R5[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0] 
    R6[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0] 
    R7[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]
*/

var row0 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
    row1 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    row2 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    row3 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    row4 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    row5 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    row6 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    row7 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];

var field = [row0,row1,row2,row3,row4,row5,row6,row7];
console.log(field[0][0]); // Get the first item in the array
```

Clicking on a column sends a number from 1-8 (8 columns), this goes into the following function:

```
function doeZet(id) {

    // check alle cellen van 8 -> 0
    for (j=7; j>=0; j--) {
        console.log(id)
        console.log(field[j,id-1]);
    }
}
```

However, this returns the row id instead of the column from id, and I'm not sure how to fix this.

Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance

EDIT solution with the help of Gavriel:

```
    function doeZet(id) {

    // check alle cellen van 8 -> 0
    for (j=7; j>=0; j--) {

        if(field[j][id-1] == 0)
            {
                field[j][id-1] = 1
                console.log(j)
                return j
            }


    }
}
```

Comment: what is the id that is passed to doeZet function?

Comment: field[j,id-1]  is equivalent to  field[id-1],
correct usage should be field[j][id-1].

Comment: j is the column id in your doeZet function, but I'm not sure what do you want to get back. Can you add an example to the question?

Comment: I want to get back wether or not there is a 1 or 2 placed there (condition if == 0), the game is   called four in a row, but with 2 players versus eachother. And I want the loop to do the following if there's a number: move on to the next row in the id, place the correct player number (which it will get as a parameter) in the next one and return the column number and row number.

Comment: PLEASE edit the question, and add at the bottom the explanation of what you need. Note: your comment is still not clear, that's why I asked for an EXAMPLE, like: "with the above values in field, when I call doeZet(4), I would like to get back X." But note, your matrix is full of 0-s, it might be wise to add some other values in order to make it possible for us to understand what you want

Comment: Already got it working in the way I want it. Thanks for your help, it will now check if the position in the column is 0, if not it will move up in the column and change the next one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
console.log(field[j,id-1]);
```

You need:

```
console.log(field[j][id-1]);
```

field[j,id-1] means: field[x], xhere x is an expression: `j,id-1`, and that expression equals to `id-1`

Comment: I just figured a for loop is probably not what I need, do you have any advice on how I could achieve what I commented on my original post?